# multiple forms handles one scanner event

Tags: vb.net

I have a win 7 application in vb.net for scanner data collection, the app first shows the main form -- top level, this form contains a lot of buttons, click any button will go to second level forms, based on scanned data input, the 3 level forms can show from a point of second level form(second level form not closed at this point), close the 3rd level form, you can go back to second level form at the point it is out for 3rd level form and continue to run rest program in send level form, close second lever form you can go back to main form to click another button to go. Main form just call the scanner class to initial, it will not handle the scanner event. the 2nd and 3rd level form load has the addhandler statement. No matter which form is on top will handle the scanner event to process scanned data in that particular form, every form process that data differently. 
In order to keep the scanner event for every available form, I put the event in a module, and when the scanner class read a data will raise this event. when I test it, whatever the first available form handle the data well, and when the forms switch back and forth, the event handler not work any more, and program freeze or stop working. I cannot figure out why. I hope you guys can give me some advise about what is better way to handle this kind of event.
Thanks!

Comment: see [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

In a form, include a handler to call your function in the module. When the form is no longer active, unload the form or remove the scanner handler. If there are two active handlers for an event, it can cause problems.